# Setting HOSTNAME when connecting to Sybase from PHP

Tags: php, hostname, sap-ase

I have an Apache server running PHP 5.3.3.  Our sybase ASE servers use HOSTNAME on connect for rudimentary ID and filtering - make sure prod hosts connect to prod, etc.

Is there any way to have sybase_connect() supply HOSTNAME on connection?

I also have ODBC configured (with DataDirect drivers); or is there a way to supply HOSTNAME on ODBC connects?

Comment: Surely the hostname is looked-up by the Sybase engine; otherwise all Mr. Hacker needs to do is set his client to call itself 'SECURE_PC' instead of 'HACKER_PC'...

Comment: @Phil Lello No, it's a parameter to Sybase CTLib on the client side. I just wonder if there's a place to set it. I do not have the opportunity to change the php sybase code to support this.

Comment: I take it 'do not have the opportunity' means the 'political' hurdles to deploying non-standard code?

Comment: @Phil Lello you got it. Especially not in prod. I found my answer, there is a way. I'll answer this myself.  Thanks Phil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the source Luke...

The sybase_connect() code takes CT_HOSTNAME info from the INI string "sybct.hostname"

```
ini_set("sybct.hostname", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

Worked for me in Apache::PHP

Thanks all.